# What is the difference between String str1 = "hello"; and String str2 = new String ("hello"); in java?

Tags: java, string

What is the difference between `String str1 = "hello";` and `String str2 = new String ("hello");` in java?

I know the `str2` is a object, but what about `str1`?

I mean for example:

if both of them are object, but why

```
if(str1.toString() == str2.toString())
```

does not result a true boolean?

Comment: They are all objects, see all the related questions and answers

Comment: Both are objects. The former uses a literal String, the latter creates a new String from a literal String.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Object is a string in any case, BTW

```
if(str1.toString().equals(str2.toString()))
```

even is better

```
if(str1.equals(str2))
```

is the proper way to compare strings

Comment: @ZouZou to generate a new hash